# pbuilder-dist precise build *.dsc fails

Tags: development, pbuilder

I'm following [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/fixing-a-bug.html) tutorial on the Ubuntu on how to fix a bug, but am encountering a problem when I try to build the source package. In the section entitled '[Testing the fix](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/fixing-a-bug.html#testing-the-fix)', the reader is told to execute two command to complete the build:

```
$ bzr builddeb -- -S -us -uc
$ pbuilder-dist <release> build ../<package>_<version>.dsc
```

The first one works fine, and I get a nice collection of packages, including the .dsc file needed to build. However when I fill in the palceholders in the second one and execute it, so it looks like this:

```
pbuilder-dist precise build ../gedit_3.1.1-0ubuntu4.dsc
```

I get the following output:

```
W: /home/notgary/.pbuilderrc does not exist
E: File /home/notgary/pbuilder/precise-base.tgz does not exist
```

I've followed the [PbuilderHowTo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto) on the wiki and have created (I think) a Precise tarball using

```
sudo pbuilder create --distribution precise
```

but the only contents of my `~/pbuilder` directory is `precise_result`

What have I done wrong when setting up my build environment, and what do I need to do to fix it so I can build Precise packages using pbuilder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first need to create a pbuilder instance locally. To do that, run the command:

```
pbuilder-dist precise create
```

This will create the `.pbuilderrc` and the `~/pbuilder/precise-base.tgz` that you are missing.

After that, you can build your .dsc as normal:

```
pbuilder-dist precise build ../gedit_3.1.1-0ubuntu4.dsc
```

Comment: This is correct. One thing to add is that the way you created the pbuilder tarball put it in `/var/cache/pbuilder/` If you don't want to go through building it all over again (as it takes some time), you can manually copy it to `~/pbuilder` making sure it is named `precise-base.tgz` pbuilder-dist should then be able to find it correctly.

Comment: `~/.pbuilderrc` is not created even after `pbuilder-dist trusty create`. should I've to do anything else to stop `w: ~/.pbuilderrc does not exist`?

Comment: @neckTwi, without any kind of context, I am unable to help. Can you create a new question with everything you have tried, the steps you followed, etc?